# Set all integer columns in all tables to 0 where the value is currently null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way in SQL Server to iteratively run the following query (or to achieve the same result):

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = 0 WHERE <column> IS NULL
```

I've used the following query to get all the columns of type 'int', but how can I achieve the above requirement?

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns where data_type = 'int' and table_name not like 'v_%' and table_name not like 'sym_%'
```

Comment: why do you want to `update` all the tables? you can manipulate data while querying

Comment: I would read up on dynamic SQL.  Essentially, this means that you are using code to generate your SQL.  You can even generate this SQL with your SQL.  (If that makes any sense to you...)

Comment: Be very careful here. You need to make sure you REALLY want to do that. There are perfectly valid reasons for having NULL and just blindly updating every NULL in every integer column of every table seems like a recipe for disaster to me. Consider things like foreign keys that don't have a relationship. You would force it to have one...unless of course you don't have a row with 0 in which case it will fail.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms180169.aspx may be useful for using a cursor and some variables to achieve what you want.

Comment: You don't need a cursor here but the performance isn't a deal breaker for something like this anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange I had considered that, but only after asking this question. All of our foreign keys end with 'Id' so I could possibly use that to filter those out.

Answer (score 2):

This is reasonably simple with some dynamic sql. I would be EXTREMELY careful doing this on any system and would ask questions about why this is a good idea. I would never do this on my system but the code is actually fairly straight forward.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'Update [' + TABLE_NAME + '] set [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = 0 where [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NULL;'
FROM information_schema.columns 
where data_type = 'int' 
    and table_name not like 'v_%' 
    and table_name not like 'sym_%'

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: (How) can I use this to also set a default constraint on these columns so that they default to 0? I thought that there would be some sort of loop here that I could put an ALTER TABLE statement in as well, but I'm not familiar with this syntax (using select to update)

Comment: It isn't using a select for an update. It is using a select statement to build the dynamic sql needed for the updated statement.

Comment: Once you understand how this code works it would be trivial to modify it to create defaults for these columns. Of course just setting a default doesn't help unless you ALSO make the column NOT NULL. This brings a whole new caveat to this being a bad idea. Are you 100% certain you don't have ANY of these columns in an update or insert where a NULL could be passed?